how to properly do inverse transform for multiple pinch to zoom in kotlin android
I have been stuck on this for days. I just can't seem to get it right. I have a custom view based on a Composable in kotlin with jetpack. I've been trying to add my own two finger zoom and two finger pan to it. I have a lot of custom drag gestures so I can't just use the built in gesture detector.  Oh and I'm trying to zoom around the centroid of the pinch in or out point. I already got it to work if I just leave the zoom origin at the top left (0,0). But when I try to zoom around the centroid, I can't get the inverse transform to work properly. it alwyas gives me values a bit to the left of where I'm actually touching so that breaks all my other drag functions.
I have an awaitPointer scope, this gets called repeatedly as the OS updates us with the finger position info
//two finger gestures, zoom and pan, and merge
.pointerInput(Unit) {
    awaitPointerEventScope {

Then I have some zoom detection logic and here at the start of the zoom I save the pivot point we are going to use. pivotPoint, panOffset, and scale are all remember variable.
// Start zooming
    if(!isZooming){
        // Calculate the pivot point (midpoint between fingers)
        pivotPoint = (pointer1.position + pointer2.position) / 2f
        pivotPoint = inverseTransform(pivotPoint)
    }
    isZooming = true
    Log.d("zoom", "zooming")

    // Compute zoom change
    val previousDistance = (pointer1History[sampleSize - 2] - pointer2History[sampleSize - 2]).getDistance()
    val currentDistance = (pointer1History.last() - pointer2History.last()).getDistance()


    // Calculate the scale change
    val zoomChange = currentDistance / previousDistance
    val newScale = (scale * zoomChange).coerceIn(minScale, maxScale)
    val scaleFactor = newScale / scale

    //it seems like the cumulative offset is previous offset times new scale plus new offset?
    //Tnew = knew * Tcurrent + tnew
    //panOffset = Offset(zoomChange * panOffset.x +pivotPoint.x, zoomChange * panOffset.y + pivotPoint.y)

    // Adjust panOffset to keep the content under the pivot point stationary
    //panOffset = (panOffset - pivotPoint) * scaleFactor + pivotPoint
    //panOffset = panOffset + (pivotPoint - panOffset) * (1 - scaleFactor)

    panOffset += Offset(
        (1 - scaleFactor) * (pivotPoint.x - panOffset.x),
        (1 - scaleFactor) * (pivotPoint.y - panOffset.y)
    )

    Log.d("zoom", "panoffset: $panOffset")

    // Update the scale
    scale = newScale

and when I go to draw at the end of this I do this:

{
withTransform({
    // Step 1: Translate so pivotPoint aligns with the origin
    //translate(pivotPoint.x, pivotPoint.y)

    // Step 2: Scale around the origin (pivotPoint)
    scale(scale,scale, pivotPoint)

    // Step 3: Translate back from the origin to pivotPoint
    //translate(-pivotPoint.x, -pivotPoint.y)

    // Step 4: Apply panOffset for panning
    //translate(panOffset.x, panOffset.y)
}) {

finally I have an inverse transform the following to get the original point into my view without all the scaling.
fun inverseTransform(touchPoint: Offset): Offset {
    return (touchPoint - panOffset) / scale
}


if you want to get "inverse transform" then instead of calculating it "by hand" use invert and call map with your Offset
